# How to scrape employee counts from a LinkedIn company page using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to build a program that will search for an industry name, and click on the first profile in the list of results on LinkedIn and scrape exact employee count. I wrote the code for it, which I thought would work, but I can't seem to understand why the code isn't returning the exact employee count. The xpath seems correct - any help at all would be really appeciated!

```
import time
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/login')

nameidElem = driver.find_element_by_id('username')
nameidElem.send_keys('username_here')

pwdidElem = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
pwdidElem.send_keys('password_here')

continueElem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn__primary--large")
result = continueElem.submit()
time.sleep(10)

industry = "books"
link = "https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/companies/?keywords=" + 
industry + "&origin=GLOBAL_SEARCH_HEADER"
driver.get(link)

firstcompany = driver.find_element_by_class_name("search-result__title")
firstcompany.click()

employees = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ember1274"]')
number = re.findall(r'\d', employees.text)
print(number)
```

Comment: You don't... it's against their TOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below xpath to get the number of employees.

```
//*[.='Company size']/following-sibling::*[contains(.,'employees')]
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Make sure to wait for the element to be presented, after clicking on the firstCompany link.

**Edit1:**

Use the below xpath to 'See all **XX** employees on LinkedIn'

```
//a[@data-control-name='topcard_see_all_employees']/span
```

*CSS:*

```
a[data-control-name='topcard_see_all_employees'] span
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]